# Min and avg value using xllookup formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I need to find min and average score using xlookup() formula where teacher is Smith.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blvuy.png)

I tried min(), min(), small() but didn't work

I tried minifs() and it is working perfectly fine but unable to do so with xlookup()

Comment: If you can get minifs() to work, then you are not getting the arguments correct in xlookup(.

Comment: Why do you want to use xlookup() if it works with minifs()? Xlookup typically finds the first found from the direction you're seeking

Answer (score 1):

Xlookup will only return a single value. Use filter instead to get every value that matches the criteria then apply max or min to that.
`=FILTER(A2:A13,D2:D13=A19)` where A19 contains the name of the teacher. Then simply wrap that in your desired function. `=MIN(FILTER(A2:A13,D2:D13=A19))`